# RxJava: use timer between iterations on array

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to use RxJava for iterating over and array of numbers where each number represents a timeout I would like to perform before doing the next emission.

This is what I came up with..

```
    AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);     
    Long[] intervals = {1L,2L,3L,4L};
    Observable.fromArray(intervals)
    .zipWith(Observable.interval(intervals[index.getAndIncrement()], TimeUnit.SECONDS), (a,b) -> a)
    .subscribe(event -> {
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now());
    });
```

The problem in this code is that `Observable.interval` takes the first index in the array but ignores the `getAndIncrement()` so I get only timeouts of 1sec.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```java
Long[] intervals = {1L, 2L, 3L, 4L};

Flowable.fromArray(intervals)
.flatMap(interval -> Flowable.timer(interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                     .map(w -> interval), 1)
.subscribe(event -> {
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now());
})
```